# Access GNUPG from AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, gnupg, aws-lambda

Is there any way to get hold of the GNUPG from a Lambda Node.js function, I can see AWS uses this elsewhere but I can't seem to get access to it.

I want to encrypt some text for transmission over email using a public key.

I did try finding an NPM for it but it seems incomplete, what I did find was OpenPGP.js http://openpgpjs.org/ but I'm not sure how to include a static js file into a AWS Lambda function as it seems to error

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not to worry I found out what I did wrong, it was because the data was inside a function so it was always null, to complete the information here is now to do it:

npm install --save openpgp

or get the file from the dist.

```
var enctext, ciphertext, encoptions;
var text = "Hello world this needs to be secure";
var openpgp = require('openpgp'); 
openpgp.initWorker({ path:'openpgp.worker.js' }) // set the relative web worker path

    encoptions = {
    data: enctext,           
    publicKeys: openpgp.key.readArmored(fs.readFileSync ('./pubkey.asc','UTF-8')).keys,   
armor: true                                        
    };

    openpgp.encrypt(encoptions).then(function(ciphertext) {
    output = ciphertext.data;
    console.log(output);
    });
```

This should work